# Does segment of code inside the OnStart() in WindowsService repeat?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I learnt that the WindowsService`s OnStart() executes the segment of code inside it? Does the segment of code execute only once, which is at the start of process or does it get executed repeatedly until the process stops?

Comment: _"executes the segment of code inside it"_? Anyway no, it's **called** once when service starts.

Answer (score 1):

It runs once, and you have to `return` from it before your service is considered to be started - so if you want something to run continuously, it's up to *you* to create e.g. new threads or timers to run that code.

You would also, usually, at this time also set up any needed synchronization primitives (such as `ManualResetEvent`, or a `CancellationTokenSource`) so that you can use these inside your `OnStop` method to get your new threads/other code to exit gracefully.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could you please tell me how I can run something continuously. For example, if I want to compare a specified time with current time continuously(or at the interval of 1 second) until they match, what can I do?

Comment: Like I said, you could create a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) that you then set to run some code every second. Although if that's *all* that your service is doing, you might want to consider using the Windows scheduling system instead - there's no point in running code just to wait for a particular time of day to happen.